# Amcharts - Ammaps display multiple balloons

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, ammap

Is it possible to display multiple balloons of a mapObject in Ammaps?
I've just found that information:

http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/force-show-balloon-over-specific-data-point/

Unfortunately it is working only for single-target mapObject, because it seems to use the hover event, which cannot be fired simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from official support: "Balloon can only be one at a time."